# Where does "Whatcha" & "Didja" come from?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, register, eye-dialect, yod-coalescence

Does anyone know where "Whatcha" and/or "Didja" originate from?

Watcha:   What did you?
Didja:   Did you?

Edit:
I cannot find these words in my English Grammar books and they are not in my English dictionaries.   I don't know enough about them to even ask sensible questions.  I myself use them.   Yet, when asked about them by a non-native English speaker, I found myself clueless as to why English dropped the word "you" for a sound that had no resemblance to the word "you".

Comment: They originate from speech.

Comment: Someone downvoted this question for unstated reason but I feel it was a reasonable one to pose to this community so have voted to the contrary.

Comment: https://youtu.be/OHnFheqTTdg?t=55 speaking a combination of word quickly leads to new whole words!

Comment: This is not mere *speaquly* "speaking a combination of words quickly". Sloppy-Ellipsis is almost always the poor mans etymology! In fact, these are clitic, not eye-dialect. Clitics is where present verb inflection is thought to come from, and why Spanish e.g. can be pro-drop (omitting the subject). \*dheH- (cf. "do") is copiously attested in compound phrases that fossilized, cp. *credo* e.g., to the point that it is treated like a suffix in wiktionary's derivation-tables. Although, I don't think *whatcha*, *woulda*, *didya* were reconstructable for the parent language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These words are the transcriptions of a particular pronunciation of two words  and they represent really two words but somehow one came to represent two and three words  (whatcha). The origin of this pronunciation is explained mostly phonetically; it is a phenomenon better  understood  through an identification of the phonetic processes involved.

*Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* (pp. 49,50):

> *Assimilation* is a kind of COARTICULATION. It is the alteration of a speech sound to make it sound more similar to its neighbours. In English it mainly affects PLACE OF ARTICULATION.
>
> Yod coalescence (or 'coalescent' assimilation) is the process which changes /t/ or /d/ plus /j/ into /tʃ/ or /dʒ/ respectively. Across word boundaries it mainly affects phrases involving "*you*" or "*your*".

*Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* (p.151) Coarticulation:

> Speech sounds tend to be influenced by the speech sounds that surround them. **Coarticulation** is the retention of a phonetic feature that was present in a preceding sound, or the anticipation of a feature that will be needed for a following sound. MOST ALLOPHONIC variation — though not all — is coarticulatory.

It becomes clearer now why the word "you" is found in both combinations; however there is a gap to fill in explaining how the forms in which a separating word occurs, also came to have the same pronunciation.

From [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatcha#English):

> **whatcha ( watcha, wotcha,  wotcher,  whatchya)**
> (colloquial) Contraction of "**what are you**".
>
> - Whatcha doin'?
> - Whatcha talking 'bout?
> - Whatcha sayin'?

> (colloquial) Contraction of "**what have you**".
>
> - Whatcha been up to?

> (colloquial) Contraction of "**what do you**".
>
> - Whatcha think?
> - Whatcha got there?
> - Whatcha wanna do now?

> (colloquial) Contraction of "**what you**".
>
> - Do whatcha gotta do!

> **didja** (informal) Pronunciation spelling of "**did you**". [[Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/didja)

Comment: ( I just reformatted your answer. Always feel free to roll-back the edit.)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul   As the result is acceptable, I won't bother with rolling back; although I reckon that the writing of the name of sources in full makes for a nicer presentation, I don't think I'll do that.

Answer (score 6):

*Whatcha* and *didja* are the 'informal' spellings of *what you* and *did you* respectively. People often spell them the way they pronounce these words.
'Palatalisation' is what caused those pronunciations.

**Palatalisation** is a type of [secondary articulation](http://www.phon.ox.ac.uk/jcoleman/MULTART.htm) whereby a sound is produced with the front part of the tongue coming near the hard palate.
It's often *regressive* and is influenced by the following /j/.
In consonants, it mostly affects the alveolar obstruents (/t d s z/) when they're immediately followed by /j/, resulting in palatalised sounds. In IPA, the palatalised sounds are usually transcribed by adding a superscript [<sup>**j**</sup>] after the primary symbol.

Most secondary articulations are allophonic in English i.e. they do not change the meaning of the word. For example, 'tune' is usually pronounced [t͡ʃuːn] in most varieties of British English while most Americans pronounce it [tuːn], both of them mean the same thing.
In some languages, such as Russian, secondary articulations change the meaning of the word, thereby making phonemic contrasts. For example, [s<sup>j</sup>ok] means 'he lashed' while [sok] means 'juice'. <sub>[Example from [*Understanding Phonetics* by Patricia Ashby](https://books.google.com/books/about/Understanding_Phonetics.html?id=yKm3PAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)]</sub>

In English,

- /t/ and /j/ coalesce into /t͡ʃ/
- /d/ and /j/ coalesce into /d͡ʒ/
- /s/ and /j/ coalesce into /ʃ/
- /z/ and /j/ coalesce into /ʒ/

Most of time, the clusters /tr/ and /dr/ also undergo palatalisation and become /t͡ʃr/ and /d͡ʒr/, respectively.
So 'true' and 'drive' might sound as if they were 'chru' and 'jrive'.

Examples:

- *Wha**t y**ou*
- *Di**d y**ou*
- ***Tu**ne* (in BrE)
- *Gra**du**al*
- *Na**tu**re* etc.
- *Fu**si**on*

Words like *si**tu**ation, gra**du**al, perpe**tu**al, **Tu**esday, e**du**cation* etc., have also undergone palatalisation.

Geoff Lindsey in his book *[English after RP](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6nSKDwAAQBAJ&dq=&redir_esc=y)* explains that this coalescence/palatalisation had already happened to some words by the time of RP, e.g. *culture, future, picture,* and *soldier*, so this is not a random idiosyncrasy.

---

<sub>/j/ represents the 'y' sound as in *yes*.

/ʃ/ is the 'sh' as in *ship*.

/ʒ/ as in *genre*.

/t͡ʃ/ as in *church*.

/d͡ʒ/ as in *judge*.</sub>

Comment: This has been going on for a ***very*** long time, longer in fact than English has even existed. Consider that English *nation* ultimately derives from Latin *natio, nationis* where it originally had /ti/ in it. For even fancier versions of this sort of thing, see Spanish *leche* < L. *lactem*, *ojo* < *oculus*, *espejo* < *speculum*, *llamar* < *clamare*, et hoc genus omne.

Comment: Hmmm. Palatalisation and coalescence aren't the same thing. Most importantly, in the string you find in something like "watcha" there is no 'palatalised' /j/, rather there is a completely new and non-allophonic phoneme which replaces both the obstruent and the following yod [j]. Coalescence is indeed phonemic.

Comment: (You can't really palatalise a /j/, because it's already palatal!)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I didn't even realise while writing my answer. :/ I meant 'coalesce into...'

Comment: There's indeed no /j/. It's been lost as far as I know for instance cf. sugar and suit. The /s/ and /j/ coalesced in sugar, but suit lost it's /j/..??

Comment: Hi DC, see my comment to you under another post here. The ***palatalisation*** you describe here, namely the secondary articulation involving the raising of the 'front' of the tongue (which is the middle of the tongue in non-technical speak), is an actual phonetic process for which *palatalisation* is the standard term. However, *palatalisation* as loosely used to describe yod coalescence is just a nod to the fact that the stricture for the new affricate or fricative is retracted, i.e. is now post-alveolar or palato-alveolar. It's really a term catching a generalisation about the place ...

Comment: ... of articulation of the new obstruent. (I.e. it will be further back in the mouth). I think the latter usage of the word *palatalisation* is confusing, especially because the whole process involves a loss of *palatalisation* in the technical sense. So, for example in /tju:n/, we'll observe palatalisation of the [t], but in /tʃu:n/, for most speakers, there's no palatalisation in that same sense.

Answer (score 5):

This feature of connected speech is often called 'yod coalescence'.

Comment: That is still *palatalisation* though.

Comment: Please could you add some definition of yod coalescence?

Comment: It is a type of assimilation, coalescent assimilation.

Comment: @LPH: [It is palatalisation](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yod-coalescence).

Comment: Yes, also, that is the place of articulation; t and d are "palatalized" (where j is placed).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul No, It' not palatalisation old bean! (Dictionaries not a good source here!).

Comment: Most Phonetics Books also call it palatalisation though "Over time, there’s been a tendency for such two-consonant clusters to 
coalesce into the single affricate consonants /tʃ/ and /dʒ/. The process is 
widely known as ‘palatalization’ or ‘yod coalescence’, ‘yod’ being the name 
for the sound /j/." [Geoff Lindsey]

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Sorry, I wasn't on the ball there. My comment was as clear as mud! Yes, the coalescent assimilation of alveloar obstruent+yod clusters is sometimes (confusingly, in my opinion, as witnessed here!) referred to as the 'palatalisation' of these clusters. However, what this is referring to has nothing to do with palatalisation in the sense described in your post! 'Palatalisation' here means something like 'retraction'. The stricture for the initial obstruent moves backwards *towards the palate*, so that it is no longer alveolar, but post alveolar. A completely different thing!

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul So for example, the /t/ in /tj/ is alveolar, but the affricate /tʃ/ is **palato**-alveolar. It has regressed towards the palate.

Answer (score 4):

*Whatcha* (or *wotcha*) is a contraction of a variety of expressions: *what are/do/did/have you* - see the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatcha) entry.

Similarly [didja](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/didja).

They arose because that's how people speak.

Answer (score 2):

Whatcha is as the other answers say. Incidentally, [wotcha](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/wotcher.html) is either a contraction of the greeting 'what cheer?' (York Mysteries, c.1440) or 'what do ye?' (Chaucer c.1386).

Didja is, as you say, from 'did you?'

Like 'ain't', 'innit', 'wassup', 'bloomin' and scores of others, they're still in use in London and South East England and probably in many other parts of the country. Many such expressions are labelled 'Cockney'.

Comment: "Whatcha" as in "watcha doing?", rather than "wotcher" as a greeting, I think

Answer (score 1):

The original is "What (did/have/are/can, etc) you"

This is pronounced /hwɒt/ (verb) /juː/

The verb is unemphasised and then lost

The /juː/ is reduced to /jə/[or /ja/] the result is

/hwɒt/ /tʃə/

The two [t]s run together,

Watcha  - /hwɒtʃa/

The same applies to "didja" where the [d] and <s>[t]</s> [j] combine. *Edited 20201015*

Comment: Is there really /h/ in its pronunciation?? I have never heard the pronunciation that uses /h/.

Comment: The OED  and Merriam Webster both give a 'h' before the 'w'. Albeit MW places it in brackets.

Comment: But dictionaries don't tell you how words are used in daily life, do they?

Comment: Mine does, but then I use the OED... I suggest you say water - "/ˈwɔːtə/," and "what a" - /hwɒt ə/ a couple of times. Of course, an accent will make a difference, and dictionaries tend to give a standardised pronunciation[s].

Comment: In RP/SSBE there's no longer a /ʍ/ ('hw') there, though there used to be for some speakers a hundred years ago or so. There's still one in Scottish English. [Btw, I don't understand the /d/ and /t/ combining in 'Didja'. Which /t/ are you talking about?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Must be a typo, I've edited. *In RP/SSBE, there's no longer a /ʍ/ ('hw') there* As you wish - I'm not going to fight about it. I can hear a difference but that's subjective.

Comment: @Greybeard You might have a /ʍ/ there. My Mum did, but her Dad was Scottish and she lived there for many years.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I feel sure that it's not only me or the Scots. I, as I said, hear a difference in what and water, which and weasel. In the former, there is a hint of an aspirant.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have focused on the sound change, but not on the early usages of these forms in written writing. *Whatcha* and *Didja*, as uses in print, emerge somewhere in the late 19th or early 20th century as representations of oral dialogue.

This n-gram shows the origin point within Google's English corpus to be in the 1910s, a time when short stories and serials in popular magazines were flourishing:

[image]

Examples from Google Books:

[*Harper's Weekly*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Harper_s_Weekly/P4s-AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22whatcha%22&pg=RA23-PA18&printsec=frontcover), 1 July 1911:

> "**Whatcha** want?" she said. Ferguson gazed dully at the receiver for a full minute, in sodden and abject silence. "Hay, four-o-nine, **whatcha** want?" the voice went on, somewhat querulously.

[*Yale Sheffield Monthly*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Yale_Sheffield_Monthly/EirOAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=didja), October 1916

> "**Didja** ever see such nerve on any woman?" said Tillie indignantly. "Coming in here, and *me* showin' 'er all the stock for nothing. Say, Mae, **didja** go on that party last night?"

Using the newspaper archive America's Historical Newspapers (via [Readex](https://infoweb.newsbank.com/)), I can find uses from a couple of decades earlier. For example:

*Daily Inter Ocean* (Chicago, Illinois), December 6, 1896:

> "Say, **didja** come here t' pass remarks 'r t' eat?" demanded the waiter. "Come, **whatcha** want--er git out."

*St. Albans Daily Messenger*, 8 June 1877:

> "High bluffs, eh? Why, they ain't nothin' to what I see the other night. Why I see Jim Orndorff plank up $250 on king high and get away with the pot. **Whatcha** think o'that for a bluff?"

As you can see, these uses of *didja* and *whatcha* accompanied a style of writing that represented more accurately how the words and phrases were being pronounced.